# SQL Get previous stocks based on modified dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a pretty strange business requirement that I need to fulfill with the following two tables:

```
STOCK_TB (As of 20150319)

PRODUCT_ID STOCK_QTY 
   A          20
   B          15

STOCK_MODIFIED_TB

PRODUCT_ID MODIFIED_QTY MODIFIED_DATE_FROM MODIFIED_DATE_TO
   A          10             20150315         20150318
   B          -5             20150314         20150316
   A          -2             20150314         20150316
```

STOCK_TB represents the current stock of inventory, while STOCK_MODIFIED_TB represents the quantity of stocks modified in a date range. I need to select results of stocks for previous dates. Suppose the result was retrieved on 20150319 for dates 20150314-20150319. This is what the result should look like:

```
DATE    PRODUCT_ID  STOCK_QTY
20150314    A         18
20150314    B         10
20150315    A         28
20150315    B         10
20150316    A         28
20150316    B         10
20150317    A         30
20150317    B         15
20150318    A         30
20150318    B         15
20150319    A         20
20150319    B         15
```

In other words, the stocks for previous dates would be added/subtracted based on the date range given in STOCK_MODIFIED_TB

Is selecting data like this possible without cursors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try with this answer, of course my subquery in select  looking not so well with performance I guess... :

**[SQLFIddleExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a789e/16)**

```
SELECT cast(a.Date as date) Date,
       st.PRODUCT_ID,
       st.STOCK_QTY + isnull((SELECT SUM(MODIFIED_QTY)
                       FROM STOCK_MODIFIED_TB
                      WHERE MODIFIED_DATE_FROM <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.Date, 112)
                      AND MODIFIED_DATE_TO >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.Date, 112)
                      AND PRODUCT_ID = st.PRODUCT_ID ),0) STOCK_QTY
FROM STOCK_TB st,
 (select DATEADD(day, number, '2015-01-01') Date 
from master..spt_values 
where type = 'p' ) a
WHERE a.Date between '2015-03-14' and '2015-03-19' 
ORDER BY a.Date, st.PRODUCT_ID
```

Result:

```
|       Date | PRODUCT_ID | STOCK_QTY |
|------------|------------|-----------|
| 2015-03-14 |          A |        18 |
| 2015-03-14 |          B |        10 |
| 2015-03-15 |          A |        28 |
| 2015-03-15 |          B |        10 |
| 2015-03-16 |          A |        28 |
| 2015-03-16 |          B |        10 |
| 2015-03-17 |          A |        30 |
| 2015-03-17 |          B |        15 |
| 2015-03-18 |          A |        30 |
| 2015-03-18 |          B |        15 |
| 2015-03-19 |          A |        20 |
| 2015-03-19 |          B |        15 |
```